# Jest-cli errors

Tags: testing, react-native, jestjs

I have two error on run test . I dont solve it :/

**Node**:  v6.11.2 
**Npm** : v3.10.10

**First error is   Cannot read property 'Object.' of null**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Object.<anonymous>' of null
    at Runtime._execModule (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:510:72)
    at Runtime.requireModule (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
    at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
    at Function.bezier (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:228:13)
    at ease (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:94:14)
    at TimingAnimation._easing (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js:262:10)
    at TimingAnimation.onUpdate (/home/dby/test/jesttest/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:338:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^3.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0-beta.5",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!native-base)/",

    ]
  }
```

**When I dont use jest --no-cache , throw this error**
**Second error**

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:510
    const wrapper = this._environment.runScript(transformedFile.script)[ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like.

```
    "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
    "coverageThreshold": {
        "global": {
            "branches": 40,
            "functions": 0,
            "lines": 33,
            "statements": 25
        }
    }
}
```

And add this in the scripts.

```
"test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest --coverage",
```

Comment: thank u for answer. 
it is not related coverage :/ not work :/

Comment: You should be able to use some the structure I posted. Not sure if react-native is different with Jest. Did you include all the node modules that you need for jest?

Comment: ı dont know :/ ı find modules on the internet :/